# Rails Date Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to rails and building my first app on my own (did a few tutorials).  Wanting to build an app where the root page, search.html.erb view, is only a search bar with two params, and outputs the search result to the index view.  Thanks in advance!

What I have now:

Controller:

```
def search
    @tours=Tour.search(params[:date], params[:region])
end
```

Search View:

```
<%= form_tag tours_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :region %>
  <%= text_field_tag :date %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Tour Model:

```
def self.search(date, region)
  if date && region
    where(date: date, region: region)
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
  get '' => 'tours#search'
  post '' => 'tours#search_results'
  get 'tours/:date/:region' => 'tours#index'
  resources :tours, except: :index
```

Rake routes:

```
      root GET    /                              tours#search
       GET    /                              tours#search
       POST   /                              tours#search_results
       GET    /tours/:date/:region(.:format) tours#index
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm lost on how to render the results to the correct path; the index controller.